# What error code to return if user is over the API usage limit?

Tags: api, rest

There are two limits for the API being considered:

- Daily limit.
- Concurrency limit.

If the requests are not queued, what HTTP Response Code should be served?

The two options so far seem to be 409 and 503. That said, 503 seems to be indicating an issue with the API server itself, and not that the user calling it has exhausted their quota.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon further reading, found `429 Too Many Requests` (RFC 6585).

> **429 Too Many Requests**
>
> The 429 status code indicates that the user has sent too many
>   requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").
>
> The response representations SHOULD include details explaining the 
>   condition, and MAY include a Retry-After header indicating how long
>   to wait before making a new request.
>
> For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests    Content-Type: text/html   
Retry-After: 3600

    <html>
       <head>
          <title>Too Many Requests</title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <h1>Too Many Requests</h1>
          <p>I only allow 50 requests per hour to this Web site per
             logged in user.  Try again soon.</p>
       </body>    </html>
```

> Note that this specification does not define how the origin server 
>   identifies the user, nor how it counts requests.  For example, an
>   origin server that is limiting request rates can do so based upon
>   counts of requests on a per-resource basis, across the entire server, 
>   or even among a set of servers.  Likewise, it might identify the user 
>   by its authentication credentials, or a stateful cookie.
>
> Responses with the 429 status code MUST NOT be stored by a cache.

This seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Thank you for the other answers.

Comment: Not sure. 429 is intended for use with rate-limiting schemes. This is your "daily limit". Concurrency limit may be a different thing. (I'm still looking for a better answer so I might go for 429 for concurrency limit anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no appropriate status in my opinion. Twitter made up the `420 enhance your calm` status. As long as you document it there is no problem.

In my opinion a `403 Forbidden`, even if you specify the reason, the RFC says that the request `SHOULD` not be repeated. This makes me think of that request being rejected as long as I do not modify it.

Comment: According to [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#Unofficial_codes), Twitter switched to 429 on versions 1.1+ of its API.

Comment: it is fun they used 420 as value to ask to calm down (reference to 4/20)

Answer (score 1):

Several API vendors are going with 503 to indicate that you are going above the rate limits specified as per the API Terms of usage.

Amazon EC2 and various Google APIs are doing the same. Try a Google Search on "503 rate limit" and you will find a lot of APIs going with that. As long as you provide the detailed message and your API documentation clearly mentions it, users of your API should be fine with that.

Comment: 503 is more like the server throwing the towel. The OP is more after a 4xx errors: client being naughty, server in full control.